# Example of a continuous function s.t. $f(\overline{A}) \subsetneq \overline{f(A)}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples

This question is a subproblem of the [A map is continuous if and only if for every set, the image of closure is contained in the closure of image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/a-map-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-for-every-set-the-image-of-closure-is-contai?rq=1).

I am not able to come up with any example of a continuous function s.t. $f(\overline{A}) \subsetneq \overline{f(A)}$. Can anyone give such an example?

Comment: Sorry, I found two instances of this same question in the "Related" section. I am just referring to them. [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358951/example-of-strict-inclusion-in-continuity-condition-f-overlinea-subseteq-o?rq=1) and [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062801/examples-for-f-bar-a-subsetneq-overlinefa-with-f-being-continuous?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** : consider $f = \arctan$ and $A = \Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to think in the same line but couldn't come up with the examples that $\overline{A}$ should include such values that doesn't add any new points in $y$ values of the function but the closure of $y$ values does add.

Comment: Basically, any function $f$ that is continuous on $\Bbb R$, but such that $f(\Bbb R) \neq \Bbb R$ and is open, will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ define by $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ and $A=\mathbb R$. Then $\overline A=\mathbb R$, $f(A)=(0,1]$, and $\overline{f(A)}=[0,1]$.

---

Another example is the identity function $f$ from $\mathbb R$ endowed with the discrete metric into $\mathbb R$ endowed with the usual metric. Take $A=\mathbb Q$. Then $\overline A=\mathbb Q$ (with respect to the discrete metric). But $\overline{f(\mathbb{Q})}=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb R$ (with respect to the usual metric).

Comment: This example is also on the same line as above. Thanks.

Comment: @MUH I've added another example along a different line.

Comment: The latter example is a nice one. I just wanted to check that the function is continuous. Let $V \in \mathbb{R}$ endowed with usual metric be any open set in topological space corresponding to Euclidean metric, then $f^{-1}(V) = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q} | q \in V \}$. Now this set is also open in $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with discrete metric.

Comment: @MUH If a set $S$ is endowed with the discrete metric, then *every* function $f$ from $S$ into *any* metric space $M$ is continuous. This is so because, if $A$ is an open subset of $M$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open (because *every* subset of $S$ is open).

Comment: One off-topic question. Do you have these results in mind just because of practice or does it come naturally? I mean I can derive these results (it is quite obvious here) but since I am studying some other maths also, I end up doing the same thing again and again but still don't remember the results (not that it is important but still)

Comment: @MUH In the case of both of my answers to your question, your first suggestion is the right one: I have these results in mind just because of practice.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X \to Y$ be any continuous, non-surjective function with dense range in $Y$. Then 
$$f(\overline{X}) = f(X) \neq \overline{f(X)} = Y$$

An explicit example is given by $f: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined by $f(x) = (2^{-n} x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ since the space $c_{00}$ is contained in the range of $f$ and hence the range of $f$ is dense but e.g. the sequence $(2^{-n})_{n \geq 1}$ is easily seen to not be in the range of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:X\to Y$ where $Y$ is equipped with indiscrete topology.

Then automatically $f$ is continuous and $\overline{f(A)}=Y$ for every non-empty $A\subseteq X$.

For suitable $X$ plenty examples can be found with $\varnothing\neq A\subseteq X$ and$f(\overline{A})\neq Y$.